Merge two enumerables whilst keeping the order defined by either source
I need to merge two enumerables while keeping the relative order of items as defined in the source enumerables.
For example, if enumerable1 contains "foxtrot", "uniform" and "kilo" and enumerable2 contains "uniform", "charlie" and "kilo", the resulting enumerable should contain "foxtrot", "uniform", "charlie", "kilo".
Explanation: we know from enumerable1 that "foxtrot" appears before "uniform", and we know from enumerable2 that "uniform" appears before "charlie". Therefore we can assume that "foxtrot" appears before "uniform" appears before "charlie".
Also, we know from enumerable1 that "uniform" appears before "kilo", and we know from enumerable2 that "charlie" appears after "uniform" and before "kilo".
Combining all that, we can tell the final order of "foxtrot", "uniform", "charlie" and "kilo".
There are cases however where this will not work, because no order can be determined or both source enumerables contradict each other.
For example, if enumerable3 contains "foxtrot" and "charlie" and enumerable4 contains "uniform" and "kilo", these cannot be merged, because one cannot tell any order. Or, if enumerable5 contains "foxtrot" and "uniform" and enumerable6 contains "uniform" and "foxtrot", these cannot be merged and an empty enumerable should be returned.
Whilst this is easy to imagine in my head, I'm having a hard time turning this into code. C# preferrably.
In this very concrete case, the maximum number of items per enumerable is 4, but I think it wouldn't hurt to have code that works independent of that.
Any ideas anyone?

What if both enumerables contradict each other? For example, if enumerable1 had "A" followed by "B", but enumerable2 had "B" followed by "A", how should that be handled?

@JohnathanBarclay that should be a "cannot merge" case, i. e. return an empty collection. I'll update the question to include that information.

Should they be in "natural" order, so like enumerable1.OrderBy(s => s) or in the order as they were in the collection?

"Whilst this is easy to imagine in my head, I'm having a hard time turning this into code". That's part of the problem. You don't go from idea straight to code. You go from idea to algorithm and algorithm to code. Put away your keyboard, pick up a pen and paper and work out the steps required to do it manually. Refine those steps into a formal algorithm and then, once you have an algorithm that works on multiple different inputs, pick up your keyboard and implement that algorithm in code. If you want to ask us how to write the code, you should already know exactly what it has to do.

@TimSchmelter no, not in "natural" order. But I notice that I picked an example where that's the case and probably shouldn't have.

@jmcilhinney well I guess it's too hot here today. Seems like I can't come up with an algorithm, that's why I'm asking. If I had one, I should be able to write the code for it.

https://chatgpt.com/share/ed3dd0ca-0c9a-4852-8b9f-4147609884b6

@user2051770: that's scary, but it's indeed working and seems to be a good algorithm.

@user2051770 Any ambiguous ordering simply chooses one of them, instead of failing as it's supposed to.  Which makes sense, the code has no mechanism to look for that case and do anything about it.

@user2051770 that is actually quite close, but it does not handle the "disconnected" case (foxtrot,charlie vs. uniform,kilo) correctly (and I couldn't convince chatgpt otherwise, unfortunately).
These things are scarily good, but still not good enough.

If you're asking about an algorithm then there should be no C# tag on this question because algorithms are language-agnostic. Don't think in terms of algorithms to begin with. Just do it intuitively at first. Once you get something that starts to feel right, then start delving into the specific logic involved. Human beings often do complex things by feel - throwing a ball to another person is a complex physics calculation but complete dunces can do it with relative ease - and that should be your first step.

@wexman sure but now you have a good starting point. Now just solve the "disconnected" problem. I was just showing that a quick query, with your own question, gives a pretty good response to get started with.

Sounds like what you may want is a topological sort, where each item depends on its immediate successor in the first enumerable or the second enumerable or both, if present in both.  If so, see maybe Topological Sorting using LINQ and/or Topological sort with support for cyclic dependencies.  You will need to think about how to handle duplicates within a given enumerable.

Your question would ne much easier to comprehend if instead of "foxtrot", "uniform", "charlie", "kilo" you had "A", "B", "C", "D" or 1, 2, 3, 4. Humans' short term memory has a pretty small size, and the way you have presented the problem consumes most of it. My suggestion is to edit the question and simplify the example accordingly.

@TheodorZoulias I actually did that in the original question, but that would lead people to assume a "natural order" of items, which is not given in this case. That's why I chose "foxtrot, uniform, charlie, kilo", because that's not sorted alphabetically, but most people know the corrector order ever since bloodhound gang...

I've edited my answer to check for duplicates and contradictions.  It should now work in all cases.  The check for each was to make sure neither the source lists nor the returned list contained duplicates.  (If there was a contradiction, then the sorted returned list would have duplicates)
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        IEnumerable<string> l1 = new List<string> { "uniform", "charlie", "kilo" };
        IEnumerable<string> l2 = new List<string> { "kilo", "uniform", "charlie" };
        try {
            IEnumerable<string> result = Merge(l1, l2);
            foreach (string s in result) {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T> (IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2) {
        if ((list1.Distinct().Count() != list1.Count()) || (list2.Distinct().Count() != list2.Count()) ) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn't merge.  One or both lists contained duplicates.");
        }
        
        if ((list1.Count() == 0)) {
            return list2;
        }
        if ((list2.Count() == 0)) {
            return list1;
        }
        List<T> newList = new List<T>();       
        bool matchfound = false;
        for(int i = 0; i< list1.Count(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list2.Count(); j++) {
                if (list1.ElementAt(i).Equals(list2.ElementAt(j))) {
                    matchfound = true;
                    newList.AddRange(Merge(list1.Take(i), list2.Take(j)));
                    newList.Add(list1.ElementAt(i));
                    newList.AddRange(Merge(list1.Skip(i + 1), list2.Skip(j + 1)));
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (matchfound) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!matchfound) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not merge");
        }
        if (newList.Distinct().Count() != newList.Count()) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn't merge.  Contradiction in lists.");

        }
        return newList;
    }

}


Forgot to mention it assumes no duplicates and no contradictions, but I don't think it'd be that hard to fix

Thanks for your answer! I was able to handle the disconnected case, but I don't know how to fix the "no contractions" one. Will keep trying!

@wexman added a simple check for duplicates and should now work in all cases, if suits you please remember to mark answer

The cost of this approach is the complexity is really bad.

Complexity?! It's like 10 lines of code

Marked as answer as it does exactly what i requested. Thanks!
Extra thanks though to @RotundChincilla for the explanation!

@publicwireless How many times does it iterate through the IEumerables. What does that mean if they aren't a trivial list. How much could you save by just pre-materialising the lists?

Despite the nested for loops it's not O (N-squared) due to the break statements.  If you have a hard time seeing that try stepping though it in VS debugger

Overview
The first thing that occurred to me when reading the problem was "this sounds like a graph problem". In this case, the items in your enumerables are the nodes, and the order of the enumerables form the edges.
For example, consider "A-B-C-D" as one of the input enumerables. We can convert this to a graph like so:
A --> B --> C --> D

If the second input is "B-X-Y-C", by itself it forms the graph:
B --> X --> Y --> C

We can now represent the problem as a merged graph where duplicate nodes are folded into one, combining the incoming and outgoing edges.
A --> B -----------> C --> D 
      |              ^       
      |              |       
      +-> X --> Y ---+       

From this, we can construct the "merged ordering" by going from left to right, only adding a node to the ordering if all the nodes that lead into it are already present in the ordering. In this example, the merged ordering is: "A-B-X-Y-C-D".
As user "dbc" mentioned in a comment, this lines up with the definition of a topological sort, an ordering of graph nodes where each node only appears after its dependencies.
Furthermore, using the graph construction, we can now formally define an ordering "contradiction" as a cycle in the graph. If node "I" points to "J", and "J" points to "I" (as in the inputs "I-J" and "J-I"), you can envision how the resulting graph has the nodes "I" and "J" pointing to each other in a loop.
We must also consider the situation where there are several "entry" and "exit" points, e.g. given inputs "M-N-O-P" and "Z-N-X-Y", which forms an X-shaped graph with "M" and "Z" pointing to "N", and "N" branching out into two chains "O-P" and "X-Y". This can be handled by allowing the first input to take precedence and merge the individual elements on equal branches sequentially. This would form the ordering: "M-Z-N-O-X-P-Y". Alternatively, we could merge the branches themselves sequentially: "M-Z-N-O-P-X-Y". Both are valid topological sortings. At the time of writing this, the initial question does not address which ordering is preferred.
Finally, we have one more case where the two graphs are disjoint, e.g. given inputs "A-B-C" and "X-Y-Z". These two chains have no shared elements. According to the problem, this should result in a failure, and return an empty ordering. This can be handled as a separate case, perhaps by scanning the enumerables for the presence of at least one shared node before committing to any other work.

Algorithm Design
At a high level, we can break the problem into two parts: constructing the merged graph, and forming the ordering. There are several algorithms for topological sorting, so the data structure that holds the graph will depend on which algorithm is chosen.
In this case, I will use Kahn's Algorithm, which has a very clean pseudocode template located on Wikipedia. Kahn's Algorithm requires two things: a graph that tracks incoming and outgoing edges, and a list of "start nodes" (nodes with no incoming edges).
The data structure for the graph can be a modified adjacency list, which keeps each node as a key in a dictionary, and the value for each being a list of immediately adjacent nodes. While the typical adjacency list only stores outgoing edges, we can track incoming edges as well by adding a second list for each key. This would look like:
"B" : {
    "nodes that point into this one": [
        "A"
    ],
    "nodes that this one points to" : [ 
        "C"
    ]
},
...

To avoid having to scan the graph post-construction for the "start nodes", we can simply track the potential start nodes while building the graph, and remove them as a candidate if they ever receive an incoming edge. Given the context of the problem, we know that the only potential start nodes are the elements at the beginning of an enumerable-- everything afterwards definitely has a node that points into it.
With that laid out, let us design the code to construct the graph and list of "start nodes". Conceptually, we simply need to iterate over each enumerable, add each element as a node, and draw an edge between it and the previous element. If a node already exists in the graph, we add the edge to the existing node instead of adding a duplicate of it.
(I wrote my code in Python for ease of testing, it should be fairly straightforward to convert it to C#.) EDIT: C# version provided at the end.
def ConstructGraph(*args):
    graph = {}
    start_points = []
    for enumerable in args:
        AttachToGraph(graph, enumerable, start_points)
    return graph, start_points

        
def AttachToGraph(graph, enumerable, start_points):
    seen_nodes = set()
    previous_node = None

    ## Tentatively add the first element as a start point.
    if enumerable[0] not in graph and enumerable[0] not in start_points:
        start_points.append(enumerable[0])

    for current_node in enumerable:
        ## Handle the obvious error case where a node is repeated in the same enumerable (e.g. "A, B, A")
        if current_node in seen_nodes:
            raise f"Found duplicate in enumerable."

        ## Add the element as a node.
        if current_node not in graph:
            graph[current_node] = {"outgoing": [], "incoming": []}

        ## Draw the edge between the current node and the previous one.
        if previous_node != None:
            graph[previous_node]["outgoing"].append(current_node)
            graph[current_node]["incoming"].append(previous_node)

            ## If we find a start point with an incoming edge, it's not a start point.
            if current_node in start_points:
                start_points.remove(current_node)

        seen_nodes.add(current_node)
        previous_node = current_node

As an example, calling ConstructGraph("ACFG", "BCDEF") will form the following graph: Graph with nodes A and B pointing C, which points to F and D. Node D points to E, which points to F. Node F points to G.
The expected ordering once we finish our topological sort is (very conveniently): "ABCDEFG".
Here's my Python implementation of Kahn's Algorithm, using the pseudocode on Wikipedia as a template. I've named the variables with the pseudocode's variable names as a prefix, plus a more understandable name.
def Kahn(graph, start_points):
    S_queue = start_points[:] ## We could re-use start_points, but let's clone it for clarity.
    L_ordering = []
    while len(S_queue) > 0:
        N_node = S_queue.pop(0)
        L_ordering.append(N_node)

        ## Clone the edge list to avoid problems when iterating
        destinations = graph[N_node]["outgoing"][:] 

        for M_destination in destinations:
            ## Remove the edge both ways.
            graph[N_node]["outgoing"].remove(M_destination)
            graph[M_destination]["incoming"].remove(N_node)

            ## Once all the dependencies are in the ordering, enqueue the destination node.
            if len(graph[M_destination]["incoming"]) == 0:
                S_queue.append(M_destination)

    ## Check for cycles.
    for N_node in graph:
        if len(graph[N_node]["outgoing"]) > 0 or len(graph[N_node]["incoming"]) > 0:
            return []

    return L_ordering

Putting the functions together, we can do the following:
graph, start_points = ConstructGraph("ACFG", "BCDEF")
print(Kahn(graph, start_points))
## prints "ABCDEFG"

This code does not handle disjoint enumerables, as this can be solved ahead of time by implementing a check to see if the given enumerables share an element or not.

EDIT: C# Version
(I might have bitten off more than I can chew by trying to make it generic, this code assumes TObject is not a complex reference type. Please modify the code to suit your needs.)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Merge
{
    public static List<TObject> MergeLists<TObject>(params IEnumerable<TObject>[] enumerables)
    {
        (Dictionary<TObject, Dictionary<string, List<TObject>>> graph, List<TObject> startPoints) = ConstructGraph(enumerables);
        return (graph == null) ? new List<TObject>() : Kahn(graph, startPoints);
    }


    private static (Dictionary<TObject, Dictionary<string, List<TObject>>> Graph, List<TObject> StartPoints) ConstructGraph<TObject>(params IEnumerable<TObject>[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<TObject, Dictionary<string, List<TObject>>> graph = new Dictionary<TObject, Dictionary<string, List<TObject>>>();
        List<TObject> startPoints = new List<TObject>();

        foreach (IEnumerable<TObject> enumerable in args)
        {
            try
            {
                AttachToGraph(ref graph, enumerable, ref startPoints);
            }
            catch // I advise defining a custom exception type, or alternatively pre-sanitizing the enumerables.
            {
                graph = null;
                break;
            }
        }
        return (graph, startPoints);
    }

    private static void AttachToGraph<TObject>(
        ref Dictionary<TObject, Dictionary<string, List<TObject>>> graph,
        IEnumerable<TObject> enumerable,
        ref List<TObject> startPoints)
    {
        HashSet<TObject> seenNodes = new HashSet<TObject>();
        TObject previousNode = default;
        bool isStartOfEnumerable = true;

        if (!graph.ContainsKey(enumerable.ElementAt(0)) && !startPoints.Contains(enumerable.ElementAt(0)))
        {
            startPoints.Add(enumerable.ElementAt(0));
        }

        foreach (TObject currentNode in enumerable)
        {
            // Sanity check the enumerable.
            if (seenNodes.Contains(currentNode))
            {
                throw new Exception("Found an obviously invalid IEnumerable."); // If you're going with this, define a custom exception.
            }

            if (!graph.ContainsKey(currentNode))
            {
                graph.Add(currentNode, new Dictionary<string, List<TObject>>{
                    {"outgoing", new List<TObject>()},
                    {"incoming", new List<TObject>()}
                });
            }

            if (!isStartOfEnumerable)
            {
                graph[previousNode]["outgoing"].Add(currentNode);
                graph[currentNode]["incoming"].Add(previousNode);

                if (startPoints.Contains(currentNode))
                {
                    startPoints.Remove(currentNode);
                }
            }

            seenNodes.Add(currentNode);
            previousNode = currentNode;

            // Update flag.
            if (isStartOfEnumerable)
            {
                isStartOfEnumerable = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<TObject> Kahn<TObject>(
        Dictionary<TObject, Dictionary<string, List<TObject>>> graph,
        List<TObject> startPoints)
    {
        // Note that this creates a shallow copy, update this to deep-copy if needed.
        Queue<TObject> queue = new Queue<TObject>(startPoints);
        List<TObject> ordering = new List<TObject>();

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            TObject node = queue.Dequeue();

            ordering.Add(node);

            // Modify to deep-copy if TObject is a complex reference type.
            List<TObject> destinations = new List<TObject>(graph[node]["outgoing"]);

            foreach (TObject destination in destinations)
            {
                graph[node]["outgoing"].Remove(destination);
                graph[destination]["incoming"].Remove(node);

                if (graph[destination]["incoming"].Count == 0)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(destination);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (TObject node in graph.Keys)
        {
            if (graph[node]["outgoing"].Count > 0 || graph[node]["incoming"].Count > 0)
            {
                return new List<TObject>();
            }
        }

        return ordering;
    }
}

Use like so:
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "D", "F" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
List<string> result = Merge.MergeLists(list1, list2);

// 'result' has the order "ABCDEF".


"it should be fairly straightforward to convert it to C#" -- If it's straightforward, why aren't you doing it then? This is a C# question, and not all C# developers know how to convert Python code to C#.

@TheodorZoulias Good point, I was caught up in laying out the algorithm design and forgot to go back to finish that. Will add it to the post.

Thanks for your answer. I was able to handle the "foxtrot, charlie", "uniform, kilo" (disconnected) case.
However, this fails for the "foxtrot, charlie, kilo", "uniform, charlie, kilo" case where it returns "foxtrot, uniform, charlie, kilo", but it shouldn't. I'm not sure how to handle this...

@wexman What is your expected output for that case? (Renaming the nodes because the abbreviated ordering produces some....explicit language): "A-B-C" merged with "Z-B-C" forms a Y-shaped graph, with both starting elements ("A" and "Z") pointing to a chain of "B-C". Assuming you want the first enumerable to take precedence, the result should be "A-Z-B-C" because both "A" and "Z" come before "B-C", which lines up with the output you have.

Sorry for backing here so late, I was out of office for a couple of days. First of all, I'd like to mention that you @RotundChinchilla deserve extra points for the detailed explanation here. You would have deserved the answer mark as well, but to be fair public wireless was faster.
As for the A-B-C Z-B-C case, in my very special case the desired output is en empty ienumerable, but in general I guess A-Z-B-C would be equally valid as Z-A-B-C.

@wexman Thank you for elaborating. No worries, I'm just happy to be able to contribute.
